# Magento2 "must" search (logic AND) and exclude small words

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

i managed magento default search to only show products with AND logic instead of OR, which was default, via the following file in custom module.

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml 

change <queryReference clause="should" ref="search" /> 
to <queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />
```

Now everything is pretty fine, and also with my hundred thousands products the search works like a charm.

But...

If a customer searches for small words (here in Italy we are plenty of) of two or even 1 letter the search shows no results.

Example: 
product: "Elementi di fisica tecnica - Lorenzini Giulio"
search: "elementi di fisica" shows no result
search: "fisica Lorenzini" show correct product

I asked my service provider to change the following my.ini

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=1
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
```

He declined because the memory usage will be too heavy for the machine

I was thinking about passing the query without 1-2letter words and I ask for your help to get advice for what to do and if it could be a good idea.

Thanks in advance 
Davide www.scontolibri.com